# looping for identify missing observation in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a looping to identify missing order.
Lopping at below

```
id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
ido<-c("b","d","f")
m<-c(4,8,10)
dat<-cbind(ido,m)
mv<-NULL
for(i in 1:7){
    for(j in 1:3){
    if(id[i]==ido[j]){mm=m[j]}
    else {mm="NA"}
    }
    k<-mm
    mv<-c(mv,k)
}
dat<-cbind(id,mv)
```

it get

```
     id  mv  
[1,] "a" "NA"
[2,] "b" "NA"
[3,] "c" "NA"
[4,] "d" "NA"
[5,] "e" "NA"
[6,] "f" "10"
[7,] "g" "NA"
```

where I expect results

```
     id  mv  
[1,] "a" "NA"
[2,] "b" "4"
[3,] "c" "NA"
[4,] "d" "8"
[5,] "e" "NA"
[6,] "f" "10"
[7,] "g" "NA"
```

and how if the id is in time format?

Comment: After calling `library(dplyr)` do `left_join(data_frame(id), data_frame(ido, m), by = c("id" = "ido"))`

Comment: You shouldn't be using a matrix here.  You are mixing character and numeric classes.  A data frame would be more appropriate.  Additionally, you should not use `"NA"` as a character for missing values.  It should be `NA`.  Maybe a read of [Intro to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) would be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your second loop (`j`) is that only the last occurence `mm` is returned. Alternatively to the previous solution, using `base R` and your loop, you can use the following:

```
## Data initialisation
id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
ido<-c("b","d","f")
m<-c(4,8,10)
dat<-cbind(ido,m)
mv<-NULL

## Loop1
for(i in 1:7){
    ## Initializing mm
    mm <- NULL
    ## Loop 2
    for(j in 1:3){
        ## Check if id is in ido (return m)
        if(id[i] == ido[j]){
            mm[j] <- m[j]
        } else {
            mm[j] <- NA
        }
    }
    ## Checking if any id was in ido
    if(any(!is.na(mm))) {
        k <- mm[which(!is.na(mm))]
    } else {
        k <- "NA"
    }
    ## Updating mv
    mv <- c(mv,k)
}
dat<-cbind(id,mv)
#     id  mv  
#[1,] "a" "NA"
#[2,] "b" "4" 
#[3,] "c" "NA"
#[4,] "d" "8" 
#[5,] "e" "NA"
#[6,] "f" "10"
#[7,] "g" "NA"
```